# Import a breaked matrix from file with python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I found myself trying to find an easier way to solve this problem, for which I've been using loops.

I have a txt file that contains a matrix in the form:

```
    a       b       c        d       e
a value1 
b value2  value3
c value4  value5  value6
d value7  value8  value9  value10
e value11 value12 value13 value14 value15
f value16 value17 value18 value19 value20
g value21 value22 value23 value24 value25

    f      g
f value26 
g value27 value28
```

I would like to create a Dataframe (of g x g) in a faster and more elegant way than loops (if there is one).

If possible I would like to actually have a column in the way:

```
index  value 
 a-a   value1
 a-b   value2
 a-c   value4
 a-d   value7
 a-e   value11
 a-f   value16
 a-g   value21
 b-b   value3
 b-c   value5
 b-d   value8
 b-e   value12
 b-f   value17
 b-g   value22
 c-c   value6
```

and so on

This is due to the fact that the Dataframe should be from several files to have one next to the other (and the value header should be the filename)

Any insight would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything? Where does this data come from?

Comment: Yes, I've try and have it working, looping throughout the lines (using plain and basic python). I am looking for a more efficient and elegant way to achieve this

Comment: That’s just repeating what you already said in your post, though.